# Two threads ping-ponging work between them causing CPU frequency to drop since none of them are 100% busy

Tags: multithreading, optimization

The background for my question is that I have a game engine whose main rendering loop involves two threads: In short, one thread generating OpenGL commands and another thread that takes the generated OpenGL commands and dispatches them to the driver. This allows them a certain degree of overlap of the work, but they still have to wait for each other at certain points. This is of course a fairly specialized situation local to me, but I also can't imagine the situation of having two threads ping-ponging work between them with a limited degree of parallelism is a particularly uncommon scenario.

Now, my problem is that, since none of the two threads are 100% busy, but rather spends some time sleeping waiting for the other thread to catch up, my OS scheduler apparently thinks that I'm not using the CPU enough to clock it up to maximum frequency. In marginal situations, this causes me to drop FPS significantly. This is on Linux with the default `powersave` cpufreq governor. Setting it to `performance` makes the problem go away entirely, but that's obviously not the default, and not what other people will be using. I don't have any Windows systems readily available to test on, so I don't know if Windows' scheduler has a similar behavior. My program is written in Java, but I can't imagine that to have any significant bearing on the problem.

Again though, I'm sure I'm not the only one with a program that behaves in this manner. Has someone else had this problem? Is there a good way to "solve" it? It seems a bit unnecessary to be dropping performance significantly just because the operating system doesn't really understand that the CPU is in fact being used to 100%.

Comment: Are you certain that’s the reason?  Often CPU frequency is throttled back because too much power is being used (or too much heat is being generated), rather than too little.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner: As I mentioned, if I just switch the cpufreq governor from `powersave` to `performance`, the problem goes away completely. Given that, I have found it hard to find any other explanation.

Comment: The explanation that would occur to me is that `powersave` mode is dialling down the frequency to reduce power usage.  I suppose you could test that hypothesis a bit by modifying one or both of your threads to do a simple `while(1) {/*empty*/}` type of spin-loop so that it uses 100% of a core, and see how the computer behaves in that scenario; if my hunch is correct, you'll see similar behavior then.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner: Not sure how I would do that modification while still performing useful work for the other thread to wait on, but it's not like any other program behaves in this way. Single-threaded programs get maximum CPU frequencies, and multithreaded programs where each thread stays on the CPU without sleeping also get maximum frequencies. While running this particular program, the CPU temperature hovers around 50 °C, so it's hard to imagine that it's throttling.

Comment: You wouldn't perform useful work; rather you would deliberately break your program just so that you could see how the deliberately-broken behavior affects the behavior of the powersave mode.  As soon as you'd made your observations, you'd revert the change, of course.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner: Yes, my point being that if I hang one of threads like that, then the other won't receive any work and will be completely idle instead. Unless I'm misunderstanding you, it would just be like running `yes >/dev/null`. Which, if I do that, the CPU clocks up to max frequency.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner: I did figure out a way to make one of the threads spinlock instead of sleep while waiting for the other, and that also fixed the issue. (But is, of course, not something I'd like to actually use.)